# Is it okay to have a special commit for each version increment?

Tags: git, version-control, incremental-build

I have a `manifest.json` file in my project and a build process that uses that file and creates the deliverable to be sent to the customer (they are beta testers). So here's what I do. I do a number of commits for development and bugfixes each time and when I think I'm ready I create **another commit** just to increment the version in the `manifest.json` file. It looks like this:

```
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 {
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Blah Blah Blah",
-  "version": "0.4.2",
+  "version": "0.4.3",
   "description": "Description goes Blah Blah Blah ha ha!",
   "content_scripts": [
     {
~
~
```

Is this okay? Any other suggestions. Am I polluting commits?

Comment: Don't store a version in a file, and this problem (and many, many others) vanishes.  Let the build system generate the version from a tag.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Can you elaborate on this solution.

Comment: It depends on the build system.  If you are using gradle, there are tools like https://github.com/palantir/gradle-git-version.  For autoconf, use something like `m4_esyscmd([{ git describe --tags --dirty || echo unknown; } | tr -d \\n])`.  The idea is that instead of storing a static manifest in the vcs, you generate the manifest and inject a version derived from a tag.  It makes the eventual artifact much more reliable.  (eg, you don't have 500 different versions all with the version "1.4.5-PATCH".)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this okay? Any other suggestions. Am I polluting commits?

It looks perfectly fine to me, and this is useful to set special tags on it and such.

If you're concerned about disk space for example, when doing this way, Git will record only the `manifest.json` itself, the rest being already referenced  in existing objects. So the footprint of such a commit will remain minimal.

**EDIT** (to include what we've discussed in comments below).

It's always a good idea to prepare "cooked" commits before submission, as well as forming "logical units". It's even required when submitting patches to a maintainer (at least in Linux kernel project), so this one can reject some of your patches if needed, while keeping on merging the rest.

In that way, separating technical enhancements and administrative stuff is a good thing. As regards the Linux kernel once again, Linus Torvalds itself does the same on Linux's main branch. The following commit simply switch to "5.13-rc1" version.

[Commit 6efb943b861 on kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6efb943b8616ec53a5e444193dccf1af9ad627b5)
[Commit 6efb943b861 on github.com](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/6efb943b861)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not concerned about disk space, I just want to know what's the best practice for this,

Comment: The best practice will depend on your workflow and guidelines of project you're working on. But on global view, one is always encouraged to prepare "cooked" commits. So separating technical stuff and administrative taks is a good idea, especially you if later need to revert one of them. Aside of this, Linus Torvalds do the same on Linux kernel (check out commit 6efb943b861 for example, which simply switch to 5.13-rc1 version).

Comment: for others who want to see Torvald's commit referred above https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/6efb943b861

Comment: Thanks for the link (it was a bit too long to include it in previous comment). If you're OK, I'll edit my answer above to include what we've just said here.